# Sum of differences over a JSONB array field in CockroachDB

Tags: json, cockroachdb

I have a bunch of jsonb objects named **text** that all follow the same structure in a table called **texts** that when selected with following query looks like this:

> select jsonb_pretty(text) from texts limit 1;

```
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                "speaker": null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                "start": 0.02,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                "stop": 2.25,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                "text": "random text 123"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            },                

            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                "speaker": null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                "start": 291.45,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                "stop": 291.88,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                "text": "random text 123"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                "speaker": null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                "start": 292.07,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                "stop": 293.63,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                "text": "random text 123"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
       ],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  []                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
]
```

I would like to sum over all the differences (stop-start) in the jsonb objects of the table.

such that the first object results in : (2.25-0.02)+(291.88-291.45)+(293.63-292.07) = 4.22 which would then need to be summed with the rest of entries in the table.

I have tried a bunch of different way of querying the objects but I can't find anything that works, any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version that works with CockroachDB (tested with v2.1.5):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data (
    id serial primary key,
    data jsonb not null
);

INSERT INTO test_data (data) VALUES
    ('[[{"speaker":null,"start":0.02,"stop":2.25,"text":"random text 123"},{"speaker":null,"start":291.45,"stop":291.88,"text":"random text 123"},{"speaker":null,"start":292.07,"stop":293.63,"text":"random text 123"}],[]]'::jsonb),
    ('[[{"speaker":null,"start":0.05,"stop":1.97,"text":"random text 123"},{"speaker":null,"start":260.78,"stop":261.23,"text":"random text 123"},{"speaker":null,"start":272.07,"stop":273.73,"text":"random text 123"}],[]]'::jsonb)
;

SELECT test_data.id,
    sum((items.item->>'stop')::numeric - (items.item->>'start')::numeric)
FROM test_data
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(data#>'{0}'::string[]) AS item FROM test_data) AS items ON (items.id = test_data.id)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

...resulting into:

```sql
          id         | sum   
+--------------------+------+
  432708358512836609 | 4.22  
  432708358512869377 | 4.03  
(2 rows)
```

Explained:

```
               tree               |    field    |    description     
+---------------------------------+-------------+-------------------+
  sort                            |             |                    
   │                              | order       | +id                
   └── group                      |             |                    
        │                         | aggregate 0 | id                 
        │                         | aggregate 1 | sum(column6)       
        │                         | group by    | @2                 
        └── render                |             |                    
             └── join             |             |                    
                  │               | type        | inner              
                  │               | equality    | (id) = (id)        
                  ├── project set |             |                    
                  │    └── scan   |             |                    
                  │               | table       | test_data@primary  
                  │               | spans       | ALL                
                  └── scan        |             |                    
                                  | table       | test_data@primary  
                                  | spans       | ALL                
(17 rows)
```

With the full support of PostgreSQL, you could use `LATERAL` joins and `GROUP BY ROLLUP` to also get the total sum:

```sql
SELECT id, sum((items->'stop')::numeric - (items->'start')::numeric)
FROM test_data, LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(data#>'{0}') AS items
GROUP BY rollup(1)
ORDER BY 1 NULLS LAST;
```

...result:

```sql
 id | sum  
----+------
  1 | 4.22
  2 | 4.03
    | 8.25
(3 rows)
```

Explained (actually simpler than in CockroachDB due to no join and sorting by index):

```
                                           QUERY PLAN                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=0.16..4815.59 rows=1271 width=36)
   Group Key: test_data.id
   Group Key: ()
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.16..2577.21 rows=127000 width=36)
         ->  Index Scan using test_data_pkey on test_data  (cost=0.15..37.20 rows=1270 width=36)
         ->  Function Scan on jsonb_array_elements items  (cost=0.01..1.00 rows=100 width=32)
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Executing this query, albeit modified as: SELECT id, sum((jsonb_array_elements(text#>'{0}')->'stop')::numeric - (jsonb_array_elements(text#>'{0}')->'start')::numeric)
FROM texts
GROUP BY rollup(id);

yields the following error: pq: jsonb_array_elements(): unsupported binary operator: <jsonb> #> <string> (desired <jsonb>)

Comment: Sorry, but that won't work anyway (even if there was no error) because of two things: 1.) `jsonb_array_elements` returns a set (rows) and cannot be used directly as arguments to aggregate functions. 2.) The order of the items returned by `jsonb_array_elements` is not specified, so you might end up comparing `stop` from entry #3 with `start` from entry #1. In any case you're just doubling the work here, which is why I've used a `LATERAL` set-returning function call. Btw. which version of PostgreSQL are you running with?

Comment: It runs on a cockroachdb from what I understand it should be somewhat similar to postgres

Comment: OK, in that case you should replace PostgreSQL with CockroachDB in all occurrences. Yes, they inherit a lot from PostgreSQL, but in this case, they don't support `LATERAL` (see [SQL support](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/detailed-sql-support.html) for details, set-returning function calls in `FROM` clause are implicitly executed as `LATERAL`).

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of this, thank you so much for the heads-up

Comment: Also, CockroachDB doesn't seem to support `GROUP BY ROLLUP`, yet. I've provided another example without that and without a `LATERAL` join. That may work for your DB.

Comment: To make matters worse, I am pretty sure now that cockroachdb dosent support WITH either: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/sql-statements.html

Comment: I just used that one to separate out the `test_data` as a temporary table. So with the data you have just replace `test_data` in the actual `SELECT` and drop the `WITH` entirely.

Comment: I get this error: pq: jsonb_array_elements(): unsupported binary operator: <jsonb> #> <string> (desired <jsonb>)

Comment: Hm, does it help if you put parenthesis around the expression, e.g. `jsonb_array_elements( (data#>'{0}') )`?

Comment: Still throws the same error: pq: jsonb_array_elements(): unsupported binary operator: <jsonb> #> <string> (desired <jsonb>)

Comment: That indicates to me that the parser from CockroachDB is a bit incomplete here as it should evaluate the return type of the expression inside the function argument and not take the expression itself as an argument type, as it should support the [`#>`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/functions-and-operators.html#supported-operations) operation. One last try: `data#>'{0}'::text[]`

Comment: Works if you cast it to stringlist such as: jsonb_array_elements(text::jsonb#>'{0}'::string[])

Comment: now I get the error that it cannot be casted to decimal

Comment: Woah! The devil really is in the details here! OK, then try with `(items.item->>'stop')::decimal` (operator `->>` returns `string` whereas `->` originally returned `jsonb`, which might be confusing for CockroachDB here).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I've downloaded and tested the latest CockroachDB myself. Answer has been updated providing a working query.